# Still able to connect to ftp after removing ftp server from Windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

After installing IIS 7.5 on a new Windows 2008 r2 server I found that FTP was active even though it was never installed. There does not appear to be any thany third-party FTP server installed. I tried installing FTP and then removing it and rebooted after the installation and removal and still able to connect via FTP. Luckily it's not possible to login with my admin account nor could I login as anonymous. How is this possible?

Comment: How did you discover that FTP was active? What did you find? How did you confirm it?

Comment: From another computer, I just entered the command 'ftp myservername" and it responded with "Connected to myservername. 220-FTP authentication:"

Comment: Have you verified that the name resolves to the ip address of the server in question and not to a different ip address altogether?

Comment: Yes the name resolves to the correct IP and when I request a web page (HTTPS) that is unique to the server that page is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You probablly installed it with IIS. Disable the site from IIS and you should be fine.

Comment: It was not installed with IIS and there are no FTP sites listed in IIS manager.

Comment: Connect over to it and see who responds on that port: telnet host port. This will give you an idea if you have something else that might respond on that. In rare cases I've seen js ftp servers like this one https://github.com/alanszlosek/nodeftpd .

Comment: Ran a packet capture on both client and server. From the client side I see the connection being made to the server, but on the server side there are no packets from the client's IP.

Comment: Also blocking ports 21 and 23 on the server with windows firewall is not helping.